# Writing to a file efficiently after prediction python

Tags: python, file, processing-efficiency

i'm rather new to programming and am trying to reduce the time taken to write my data into a file, and i found that the writing part is the main issue.

The following is part of my code for a machine learning program:

```
filename="data.csv"
f=open(filename,"w")
headers="row,open\n"
f.write(headers)

for i in range (0,55970):
    score=rf.predict(edit[i].reshape(1, -1))
    score=str(score).replace('[','').replace(']','')
    f.write(str(i) +","+ score +"\n")
    
f.close()
```

I understand that I should be writing the data only after i have gotten all of it, but i am not sure how to go about doing it - given that i only know f.write(). Do i make a function for my prediction and return score, then create a list to store all the scores and write it in? (if that is possible)

[Edit]

```
score=rf.predict(edit)
with open('data.csv', 'w',newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['row', 'open'])
    for i in range(55970):
        writer.writerow([i,str(score[i])])
```

^ added based on new suggestion. Found that i should just do the predict and then write the rows which improved the time taken significantly!

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Using `+` to concatenate strings performs poorly as it results in the unnecessary creation of new strings that are then discarded and should be avoided. String formatting and using `join()` on a list or iterable of strings are the preferred methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSV module is a better tool for this. More specifically, `writerows()` is what you are looking for.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows

Here is an example from the docs:

```
import csv
with open('some.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(someiterable)
```

---

```
import csv

with open('data.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    writer.writerow(['row_id', 'open_flag'])
    for i in range(55970):
        score = str(rf.predict(edit[i].reshape(1, -1)))
        score.replace('[', '').replace(']', '')
        writer.writerow([i, score])
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I'm not sure how to efficiently create an iterable to input the data. I have edited my original question to add the new code i have tried using writerows().

Comment: @arangard I updated my answer for you. You don't need to compile the data and then write it all at once. I recommended `writerows` because of the way you worded your original question. Test the example I have now given and let me know if you still need help.